# How should a couple apply for Express Entry when both qualify?

Tags: canada, indian-citizens, express-entry, skilled-migration

I am an IT Professional with 12+ years of experience and hold an MBA degree from India and my wife is also an MBA degree holder and homemaker with no work experience. Currently, we are in the US on L1 visa and would like to apply for Express Entry to Canada.

1. Should both of us appear for IELTS and apply for ECA (degree validation) separately?

I would be the primary applicant (owing to the work experience) but my wife also intends to work once we move to Canada.

2. Do we need to apply for Express Entry separately or should we apply together, as a couple?

Answer (score 3):

You should apply as the primary applicant because you'll be able to get more points.

If the application is approved, both of you will get permanent residence and the right to work.

You should both take the IELTS and have your degrees assessed because your maximum point totals are reduced because of your spouse, but depending on her scores and degree, she can make up the at least some of the points.

Unless she has a job offer already, it's unlikely she would get enough points as  solo applicant.

Link to [list of points](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp)